# Examples of technical (or science in general) magazines using LaTeX

Tags: examples, journal-publishing

I have been looking for resources related to (beautifully) typesetting technical and science magazines with LaTeX. I am aware of the [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) question and it is a wonderful source of inspiration.

However, not many of those examples come with the associated source.

Some of the examples I have been looking for would include:

- Two-column magazines with modern fonts and styling, complex caption positioning for figures and high-resolution graphics and charts, besides illustrations.
- Journals with complex editorial pages, prologues, sections like classifieds or miscellaneous tidbits, etc.

I understand this might be a too broad question but I would like to update this with answers from people out there and make it a valuable resource for anyone thinking (or already working on) typesetting a great looking LaTeX magazine.

Some questions for would-be contributors:

- What styles and classes do you use mostly?
- How do you handle the independent submissions and articles comprising the magazine, and how do you choose to render these into the final compiled PDF/output?
- What makes your job easier as an editor to have a ready-set, standard library of styles and commands that allow easily typesetting formulae, code, captions, figures, Tikz pots, etc.

Comment: I don't really think this question fits this format, to be honest. It is much too broad, as you seem to realise. 'Some questions for would-be contributors...' says it all: this is not a specific question which might be reasonably answered in the space available here. A lot of it will be opinion-based. Also, I doubt that the answer to the first question will be useful because the answer will generally be 'a custom class' in the majority of cases. Also, you should ask whether LaTeX is really the right tool for the kind of document you have in mind.

Comment: What journals do, if they accept LaTeX submissions at all, is require authors to use their customised class and follow their formatting guidelines. (Else they require authors to submit Word format.) These classes constrain authors to using the journal's layout and formatting. (At least, as far as this is possible.) For a magazine - as opposed to a journal - of the kind you describe, you can use LaTeX but it is unlikely to be the best option. You can use e.g. `flowfram` but it is fighting LaTeX every inch of the way to make it do what it was never designed to be capable of.

Comment: See in [LaTeX templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/),  
[Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/templates),  
[Share LaTeX](https://sharelatex.com/templates), 
[HowtoTeX](http://www.howtotex.com/templates/) and 
[CTAN topic magazine](https://www.ctan.org/topic/magazine).

Comment: cfr: I believe it fits the format within the context of serving as a resource for people who look for things like the linked showcase question, limited to magazine publications. I do not necessarily agree with LaTeX not being a suitable medium for such publications, though. I'm not talking Wired or a tabloid here, but a scientific or technical magazine that doesn't look too arcane.

Comment: Last time I checked, IEEE requires ALL submission in LaTeX (using ieeetran class).

Comment: one "magazine-like" journal that uses latex is the [ams notices](http://www.ams.org/notices/). feature articles are prepared in "standard" latex article (preferably with `amsart` conventions) format, and reformatted in-house to fit the style.  the document class is not distributed.